# How to access document/window from shadow dom in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, web-component, shadow-dom

I am using a library (`vue-airbnb-style-datepicker`) which is trying to access the `document` object to attach some event listeners. Wrapping the vue app as a web component results into following error:

```
Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

My `main.js`:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import wrap from "@vue/web-component-wrapper";
import AirbnbStyleDatepicker from "vue-airbnb-style-datepicker";

Vue.use(AirbnbStyleDatepicker, {});
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const WrappedElement = wrap(Vue, App);

window.customElements.define("gpc-components", WrappedElement);
```

How can i use the `document` object in a web component?

Is it even possible?

If not, does a workaround exist?

Comment: ``document`` is available in the **whole** page, including shadowRoots; so there must be something else wrong. Publish the code where you use ``addEventListener``

Comment: You are absolutely right. The problem was that `document.getElementById` was trying to find an element inside the Shadow DOM and attach an Event Listener to this element, but the element was null. Thanks for your input.